# Put text into an image

Tags: image, fonts, draw

I would like to print strings with arbitrary system-supported fonts into an image, however, as I know the built-in function `putText` in OpenCV only supports limited fonts. To be specific, the function I want is something like this (if written in C++):

```
void drawString(string& s, Image& I, string& fontName)
{
    ...
}
```

And calling it like `drawString("this is a string", I, "Times New Roman")` will print string in Times New Roman font, and `drawString("this is another string", I, "Helvetica")` will print string in Helvetica font.

I prefer to using C++, but any other languages are also okay.

---

The function `drawString` should also include some code about manipulating the characters such as rotation and translation with random angles and displacement.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, ImageMagick is a great general-purpose image manipulation toolchain and API.

There is a clear correspondence between the command-line and the API. As such, you can execute the command directly from the shell:

```
 convert temp.jpg -gravity Center -pointsize 30 -annotate 0 '1Il|iO0oB8' temp1.jpg
```

[... Which maps directly to the Magick++ API](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't mention clearly, because I still want to do some processing to the characters, for example rotation and so on...